# Neural network NOT organized in layers with TensorFlow or Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

I need to implement a neural network which is NOT layer based, meaning that ANY neuron may be connected to any other neuron, and that there's no way to logically organize them in consecutive layers.

**What I'm asking for is an example or a reference to proper and clear documentation about how to implement the following:**

Originally I had my own implementation in matlab, however, I've been using TensorFlow and Keras to test simple models and it allows to tune your networks very fast and the implementations are pretty efficient, so I decided to try out more complex models, however, I just got stuck creating this type of network.

HINT: It MAY be OK to create single-neuron layers, as long as you can connect a layer to ANY layer (without caring if it is not adjacent) and to MORE THAN ONE LAYER.

I'm new to Tf and Keras, so a simple python example would be appreciated, althought, pointing me in the right direction would be OK.

This is an example network (¡loops are intentional!):
[image: example network]

I dont need to train at the moment, just to evaluate models, however, keep in mind that evaluation of this kind of network is different too, one possible way is to keep with the signal sending until output stabilices, but it is just an example.

Comment: May someone mind to explain why the question was downvoted? Didn't I explain it properly? Shall I edit it because it breaks any rule? Thanks.

Comment: There is no question here, you are just stating what you want/need. That is not a question.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro thanks for your comment. I didn't state it as a question, but in spanish, if you say "I'm new to Tf and Keras, so a simple python example would be appreciated, althought, pointing me in the right direction would be OK. " it's understood as a request. Do you mind helping me rephrasing it in english so it's absolutley clear what I'm asking for?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro btw, as you are into AI field, what do you use for such implementations? I asked about keras / tf, but I dont really care about languaje / framework, if it's worth the learning curve.